# Poor performance in updating nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a stackPane where on one of the Pane I need to represent a matrix 2D of `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` In which the opacity is updated every `X` milliseconds using a bind with a DoubleProperty. The problem is that even with very small dimensions (10x15 or 20x30) there is a lack of performance and framerate is very low.

I have used also set `setCache(true)` and `setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED)` for each Shape but nothing has changed.

Here's a part of my code:
The Cell class:

```
public class Cell{
 private Rectangle r;
 private DoubleProperty value;

 Cell(final int row, final int col, final int cellSize){
   r = new Rectangle(cellSize, cellSize, Color.BLACK);
   r.relocate(cellSize*col, cellSize*row);
   r.setCache(true);
   r.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
   value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
   r.opacityProperty().bind(value);
 }

 public void setValue(double value){ this.value.set(value);}

 public Node getNode(){return r;}
}
```

The Board class:

```
public class Board{
  private Group group;
  private Cell[][] cells;

  Board(final int rows, final int cols, final int cellSize){
   group = new Group();
   group.setCache(true);
   group.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
   cells = new Cell[rows][cols];
   for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        cells[i][j] = new Cell(i,j,cellSize);
        group.getChildren().add(cells[i][j].getNode());
       }
  }

 public void setCellValueAt(int row, int col, double value){
     cells[row][col].setValue(value);
 }

 Random r = new Random();
 double t = 0;
 public void update(){
     for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++){
             cells[i][j].setValue(Math.abs(Math.sin((double)(j)/cells[0].length*2 + t)));
         }
     }
     t+=0.01;
 }

 public Node getNode(){return group;}
}
```

Cell values in the array are updated this way:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Board board = new Board(50, 50 , 15);
    Pane pane;
    try {
        StackPane root = (StackPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        pane = new Pane(board.getNode());
        pane.setPrefSize(50*15, 50*15);
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    new Thread(()->{
        while(true){
            Platform.runLater(()->{board.update();});
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

    }).start();

}
```

Performance are very poor, even with  high `X` values (eg 50/100) ... In my application I have to handle very large matrices with low refresh rates (5/10/20).
Is there something I forget?

Comment: Can't say without knowing your application, but I'd assume creating a new `NxM` matrix every few milliseconds is your issue. Is there a reason for this? Why can't you re-use the same matrix and re-size it when needed?

Comment: I do not re-create it, it's always the same, it only updates the values.
My app for now is just this, it does nothing else.

Comment: What does `update()` do? Just change the `value` for the cells? Can you create a [MCVE]? Also consider using a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead of the background thread with a `sleep`.

Comment: Why are you creating a new property instead of working with the opacity property directly?

Comment: @fabian I did not think so Thank you! But the situation does not change.

Comment: That works just fine for me, performance seems to be no problem. You should probably use an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) for this instead of your own thread, as you are creating a lot of runnables on the FX Application Thread, and running updates more frequently than the UI repaints (by default) anyway.

Comment: Experimenting a bit, with an animation timer I don't start to see any frame drop out until I reach ~40,000 cells. With the thread, it breaks down a bit earlier (~25,000).

Comment: How id `Node` defined ?